# modf does not work properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fmodf

This code should display if first 3 digits of fractional part contains "9", but does not work. "mod" variable, surprisingly, is 0 for any number.

```
int main( void )
{
    float number, dmod;
    int mod;
    double digit_1, digit_2, digit_3;
    double search=9;

    cout<<"Enter the number:";
    cin>>number;

    mod = modf(number, &dmod);
    digit_1 = mod /100 % 10;
    digit_2 = mod /10  % 10;
    digit_3 = mod /1   % 10;

    if( (digit_1 == search) || (digit_2 == search) || (digit_3 ==search) )
    {
        cout<<"mod contains 9"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"mod does not contains 9"<<endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `null`? An `int` can't be `null`.

Comment: I mean that in the debugger mod variable is 0 for any number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `modf` returns *the fractional part*, not an integer representing the fractional part. The value returned is always less than one and then when assigned to an `int` it gets truncated down to 0.

Maybe you wanted to multiply the return by 1000: `mod = modf(number, &dmod) * 1000.0;`